# Reassign F11 in SSMS

Tags: ssms

Reassign function keys in ssms? Anyone know how?

When I'm stepping through code I keep hitting F11 in SSMS on accident. Then have to cancel too many dialog boxes. I want to change F10-F12 to just run the query.

I found the keyboard options in Tools -> Options. But that isn't going to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of SSMS do you use ?

SSMS2012 has built-in shortcuts editor (right-click toolbar area->Customize->Keyboard)

If you use SSMS2008 you will have to do that using some add-in.
I am developer of [SSMSBoost](http://www.ssmsboost.com) add-in - it has shortcuts editor.
There was also other add-in, but I have just spent a bit time now and could not find it anymore. It was "SSMS shortcuts editor" on CodePlex or at codeproject.

Comment: I'm using 2008. I'll check out the add-in.